# How to find version of the AWS Cognito service?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to log the user into the AWS Cognito service using PHP ASK.

I create the client like this

```
$client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array('region' => env('AWS_REGION',''), 'version' => '2012-10-17'));
```

Then I got this error.

```
The cognito-identity service does not have version: 2012-10-17.
```

I tried to search for the version in the AWS console. But I don't know what is wrong with AWS console. The way they organized the document is really messy. I tried to use the version in the tutorials I found. But all giving me the same error. How can I get the valid Cognito version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version that is mentioned is the API Version.

You can easily find the latest version in the [AWS PHP SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-sync-2014-06-30.html#getcognitoevents).

At the top it contains the following:

> Client: Aws\CognitoSync\CognitoSyncClient
>
> Service ID: cognito-sync
>
> Version: 2014-06-30

As you can see on the specific page for the [CognitoIdentityClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentity.CognitoIdentityClient.html), it only got added in version 2014-06-30

So you need to use 2014-06-30